# JavaScript for loop returning undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

Why am i getting undefined for isPrime(2) in the below function?
It's as if the whole if statement right after `var result;` is skipped for isPrime(2) but not for other inputs. I do not understand why this is so.

```
function isPrime(num) {
  if (typeof num !== "number") {
    throw "The input needs to be a number!";
  }

  var result;

  if (num <= 1) {
    result = false;
  } else {
    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
        result = false;
        break;
      } else {
        result = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Just change the condition in for loop I <=num

Comment: Thx. But that would make 2 a composite number (not a prime number), which would be incorrect. I just changed 'var result = true;' instead. That should do the trick.

Comment: The best thing you'll learn today is to learn how to use your browser's debugging tools. You could have stepped through your line by line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If num is 2 then this part of a code will not be executed

```
for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
  if (num % i === 0) {
    result = false;
    break;
  } else {
    result = true;
  }
}
```

since i is initially 2 and num is 2, 2 < 2 is false.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why it won't run for 2.